# Geting SSL certificates for many CNAME's?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Here is my situation:

- I own and control coolwebsite.com
- Many websites have a CNAME entry pointing to coolwebsite.com

  For example, lamewebsite.com CNAME's a.lamewebsite.com to coolwebsite.com
- There are about 50 of these other websites that point to mine, none of which I can control easily

How can I get an SSL certificate that will work with these CNAME's?

Answer (score 1):

> There are about 50 of these other websites that point to mine, none of which I can control easily

If you have no control over these web sites or their DNS settings than you should not be able to get a certificate for these. If this would be possible than it would be a serious security issue.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a shared hosting kind of setup where you host the websites for clients and allow them to point their own domains to your server and use [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) or host header to serve a correct website based on domain used in the request.

More information like is above correct, where you're getting your TLS certs from, do you want to use single cert to cover everything or a cert per domain would be useful, but in general you can get a certificate with multiple [Subject Alternative Names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) for different domain names/sites.

E.g. if you're using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), with Domain Validation, you don't need control over domain's DNS, only over content served from that domain. And if people point their aliases (CNAMEs) to your web server then you already have it.